# Adjust/personalize auto-correction on Android

Tags: keyboard, motorola-moto-g, auto-correct

Using a Moto G Play with Android 7.1.1 installed. Whenever I type the word `ie.` (that is), this is auto-corrected to one of:

```
or.
IE.
```

The auto-correction selected appears to be random (perhaps based on context). I would like to tell my phone to NOT auto-correct `ie` under any circumstances. If I meant to type `or` and accidentally typed `ie`...that one is on me!

Is there any way to adjust auto-correction by manually entering personalised phrases (such as into a dictionary)? I don't want to turn auto-correct off entirely.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the correct term is 'i.e.' (with period between 'i' and 'e')

Answer (score 1):

Add the word to your personal dictionary.If you are using Gboard:

1. Go to its settings then Dictionary.
2. Click on Personal dictionary
3. Select a language or All languages if you want to add the word for every language.
4. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button.
5. On "Type a word", enter `ie.`. Press the arrow to go back to the previous screen. (You can enter a shortcut for the word if you want but with your word being so short I don't think it is necessary).

For now on `ie.` will appear when you type and will not be auto-corrected.

Comment: This may be the answer, but attempting to add personalised terms crashes settings on my phone and does not update the dictionary.