# How to enter specific characters by typing specific words without special keys

Tags: keyboard

I would like to have my Android tablet recognize every time I enter a specific codeword or sequence of characters like, e.g. "qtqtqt" and turn it automatically into a specific symbol like, e.g. "ñ".

I am not asking how to (re)define or assign a key combination like Shift+u, but rather how to type a codeword and get it automatically turned into a symbol.

In my example, let's say I want to assign the codeword "be" to the symbol "ñ", an obviously bad choice since that is a very common word in English, but I do this for the sake of explaining my point here. Then, whenever I tried to type Hamlet's famous words (just ordinary keystrokes without Shift or Ctrl or Alt) I would get this automatically:

> To ñ or not to ñ, that's the question!

Thanks

Comment: See my response [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219440/247431).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, but I need to do it with an external keyboard, so your response doesn't apply.